# Concatenation of Sequence of Consecutive Primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a_{n,m}$ be a number formed by the concatenation of $n$ consecutive primes starting at the $m$-th prime. For example, $a_{2,1}=23$, $a_{3,5}=111,317$, and so on. Is it the case that there exist infinitely primes of this form?

Comment: I guess you want to restrict $n>1$, to avoid trivial examples.

Comment: @Wojowu Don't wanna be THAT boring!

Comment: Shouldn't $a_{3, 5}$ be 1113171923?

Comment: @DavidR. No, it's 3 consecutive primes starting with the 5th prime.

Comment: $9$ is not a prime, though.

Comment: Silly me, you're absolutely right! @RobertIsrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly yes, there are infinitely many with any given $n$, but a proof is almost certainly out of reach.  See OES sequences [A030461](https://oeis.org/A030461), [A030469](https://oeis.org/A030469), [A030473](https://oeis.org/A030473), [A086041](https://oeis.org/A086041).